# How to integrate tinymce into a custom page in Bagisto

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I have included TINYMCE script file from the webkul folder, the editor is showing but it's not working. I have tried other editors as well like Froala Editor, CKeditor 5, they seem to have the same problem.

```html
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/webkul/admin/assets/js/tinyMCE/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row align-middle">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form action="">
                <textarea class="editor"  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

     tinymce.init({
        selector: '.editor',
        plugins: 'image imagetools media wordcount save fullscreen code table lists link hr',
        toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor link hr | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | code | table',
        readonly: false,
      }).then((result) => {
            console.log(tinymce);
      }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error initializing TinyMCE:', error);
      });
      
</script>
```

Comment: alternative for wysiwyg editor is Editor.js, Editor JS with Laravel https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHKD69uqaSQUOPva2MO-mpA7svY63mudv

Comment: what is not working?  it is not saving into database?

Comment: @matheen ulla I can view the editor on the page but cannot use it.